# A recursive function that takes as an arugment and loop through all the subdirectories

Tags: bash, shell, recursion

I am writing a practice function in a shell script that will take an argument(supposedly a directory) and execute the code in it and all its subdirectories and the subdirectories of subdirectories and so on.

The function itself has been tested and worked. But I am struggling to do it recursively.

My attempt:

```
function(){
    #Some codes
    for dirs in $1/*
    do
        function "$dirs"
    done
}
```

It only execute the code on the top level directory but not the sub-directory of it.

Comment: You will do well to avoid recursive functions in any shell as each recursive call spawns a separate shubshell, which for a deeply nested directory layout can be extensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -type d -exec function.sh "{}" \;
```

Comment: what if this function takes an argument, does "function.sh" will still work? if so, how does it determind the argument without I specifying it

Comment: `"{}"` passes each filename returned by `find`, one at a time, as the first argument to `function.sh` in each successive call to `function.sh`

Comment: it keeps saying that find: 'function.sh": No such file or directory

Comment: You write the function.sh

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you:

find -type d; do; function "$dirs"; done;

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
#! /bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
f() {
    for d in $1/*
    do
        [ -d $d ] && f $d
    done
}

[ -d $1 ] && f $1
```

save it as `script.sh` and try

```
bash -x script.sh .
```

should show the dirs.

Answer (score 0):

here is a fully expanded example of a tree walker pattern

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -d '' help <<EOF
usage: $(basename $0) <parameter>

this is an example of a tree walker pattern

-v          Verbose
-h          Help
-p pattern  pattern to find
-f file     the file to process

EOF

# preset error for param validation
OPTERR=0

# presets for variables
verbose=""
pattern=""
file=""

# colours
Red='\033[31m'
Off='\033[0m'

# iterate through getopts on options
while getopts vhp:f: opt
do
    case $opt in
        v)  verbose="-v";;
        h)  echo -e "$help"; exit 0;;
        p)  pattern=$OPTARG;;
        f)  file=$OPTARG;;
        \?) echo -e "\nInvalid - $opt\n\n$help\n" >&2; exit 1;;
    esac
done

# remove found args leaving the parameter behind
shift $((OPTIND-1))

parameter="$1"

if [ -z "$file" ]
then
    # no file passed do a find

    if [ -z "$pattern" ]
    then
        echo -e "$help\n\n${Red}please specifiy find pattern with -p${Off}"
        exit 1
    fi

        find . -iname "$pattern" -exec $0 -f "{}" "$parameter" \;
else
    # file specified, do the work
    echo $(ls "$file")" -> "$(cat $file)
fi
```

where a tree structure like this

```
$ tree one
one
├── README.md
└── two
    ├── README.md
    └── three
        └── README.md
```

would be traversed like this

```
$ ./traveler.sh -p "*.md"
./one/README.md -> 1
./one/two/README.md -> 2
./one/two/three/README.md -> 3
```